# How to make sure, files are shared and transferred via ethernet rather than WiFi?

Tags: networking, 18.04, filesystem, file-sharing

I have two ubuntu machines, that are both connected to a local network via WiFi. But at the same time they are also directly linked with an ethernet cable.

Now on one machine I am sharing a folder by properties->Local Network Share->Share this folder. On the other machine I access that folder by clicking "other locations" in nautilus and then clicking on the machine that is sharing the folder and then I mount that folder. Now when I am copying files out of the folder I get extremely low data rates (between 0.2MB/s and 3MB/s).

However, when I unactivate the WiFi adapter on one of the machines and unmount and mount the folder again, I get transfer rates in the 50MB/s range. So apparently ubuntu prefers using WiFi for file tranfer over ethernet. How can I change this behaviour or how can I tell the system to always use the ethernet network to access this folder?

Some extra information:
I set up the IP-addresses of the ethernet network manually. The sharing computer is 10.0.0.1 and the other one is 10.0.0.2.

Comment: @user535733 Well, that's exactly what I would have expected. But as you can see, my ubuntu did prefer the WiFi connection. When I unactivated it, the file transfer instantly worked with a lot higher speed. I didn't have to do anything to "fix" the network or anything like that.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the problem. When both routes are active, do you get a lot of CPU activity? I wonder if it's a routing conflict.

Comment: Read `man ip-route`. Do `ip route` and `sudo journalctl /usr/sbin/NetworkManager` to get more information. Edit your post, don't add info in comments.

Comment: @user535733 On which machine? The one hosting the files, or the one receiving them?

Comment: @waltinator Same question: From which machine do you want this information? And I checked the commands and the output of journalctl is extremely long. I can not append all of that to my question here. Can you maybe name me some limits?

Comment: @waltinator Okay, the limit question solved itself, I just realized, that the files shows the whole history of the system. So I guess, the log of one session or maybe day will be enough. So only the question about which machine remains.